# Is it possible to create MatInput (all material Components Dynamically) in typescript?

Tags: angular-material2, angular5, typescript2.0

We have DOM object to create dynamic html input and elements.

```
For eg: var child = document.createElement(input);
child.type="text";
child.id="inputId";
var parent = document.getElementByTagName('body');
parent.appendChild(child);
```

as usual we used to create element by dom object for HTML. But how to create material components using dom object in typescript.

is there options to create dynamic way like that above for material components

```
  for eg: var child = document.createElement(mat-form-field);
```

This question am asking bcz we have planned to create custom module. so which can use it in any project in future.

Answer (score 0):

For my question the answer is

https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

With the help of custom form field control,I think, we can create dynamic angular material.

Let me try it and post regards about it further. Thanks